# scikit-learn : Installation problems

Tags: python, macos, clang, scikit-learn

I'm trying to install machine learning package **scikit-learn** in OSX unsuccessfully.

When I write the command "python setup.py install" to check if my installation is OK, I got

```
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_py
running build_clib
customize UnixCCompiler
#### ['clang', '-fno-strict-aliasing', '-fno-common', '-dynamic', '-g', '-Os', '-pipe', '-fno-  common', '-fno-strict-aliasing', '-fwrapv', '-mno-fused-madd', '-DENABLE_DTRACE', '-DMACOSX', '-DNDEBUG', '-Wall', '-Wstrict-prototypes', '-Wshorten-64-to-32', '-DNDEBUG', '-g', '-Os', '-Wall', '-Wstrict-prototypes', '-DENABLE_DTRACE', '-arch', 'i386', '-arch', 'x86_64'] #######
**Missing compiler_cxx fix for UnixCCompiler**
customize UnixCCompiler using build_clib
building 'libsvm-skl' library
compiling C++ sources
C compiler: clang++ -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict- aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g  -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe

compile options: '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include -c'
clang++: src/libsvm/libsvm_template.cpp
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'src/libsvm/libsvm_template.cpp'
clang: error: no input files
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'src/libsvm/libsvm_template.cpp'
clang: error: no input files
error: Command "clang++ -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include -c src/libsvm/libsvm_template.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/src/libsvm/libsvm_template.o" failed with exit status 1
```

I have installed clang version:

```
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Can you please help me? Any help is welcome. thanks.

Comment: Try installing gcc via homebrew, that works for me

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I have found is to just use Anaconda, which will give you just about every scientific Python package under the sun and make package management much easier in general.  You can download it here:

https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/

A list of packages that Anaconda supports:

http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs.html

Comment: I have the same problem with anaconda :\